# Better testnet environment

Tags: testnets

I'm looking for a better testnet environment for solidity development. My current flow at the moment is kinda slow:

1. Asking for ETH on testnet faucet.
2. Just deploy my smart contract to work and test.
3. Wallet is getting reset after like 1 hour or so.
4. Beggin for ETH again, now get blocked for spamming ( ropsten, rinkeby ).

Is there a better way to do this, I'm curious, this is like a 90s development environment. I'm thinking about building a private testnet, however, if there is any service we can use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there. Just to check - point 3: what do you mean the wallet is reset? That shouldn't be the case. How did you generate the private key you are using for testing?

Comment: it's their own way of running the network, I'm not sure if they check for spam or something, it keeps reset my ETH wallet to 0. It doesn't have my private key and there is no related tx to move my development fund to else where.

Comment: Which test network are you using? Can you share your address so we can check what's happening? (None of the public test networks should be resetting... No one would be able to test!)

Answer (score 1):

Use ganache.
If you want to deploy something to a public testnet though,  take a look at other blockchains such as Matic (it has a testnet named mumbai) or Fantom (it also has a testnet) these usually are much faster than ropsten

Comment: thanks for letting me know regarding Fantom and Matic, didn't know that. For now I just deployed my own private testnet using hardhat and it works great so far.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to see you managed to solve your problem